# A standalone executable for ARMv7 fails because it "cannot open shared object file" for libstd

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am attempting to build a standalone Rust based binary using:

```
cargo --target=armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --release
```

Anytime I build the binary for the target system and copy and execute that binary on the target it will panic:

```
<binary>:error while loading shared libraries: 
 libstd-42431e74081a30a8.so: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This means it cannot find a dynamic library.

If the dynamic libraries are copied to an external SSD and there is a path to them, the binary will not panic as it finds the libraries.

Originally the .cargo/config had

```
rustflags = ["-C","target-feature=prefer-dynamic]
```

I have also tried

```
rustflags = ["-C", "target-feature=+crt-static"]
```

But the binary still requires the external dynamic libs

The .cargo/config file contents are:

```
[target.armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]
ar = "arm-dey-linux-gnueabi-gcc-ar"
linker = "gcc-sysroot"

[build]
rustflags = ["-C", "target-feature=+crt-static"]
```

I expect that the target's binary will execute without the dependencies on dynamic .so or .rlib system files as we have a space constraint system where the SSD may not be there.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity (as I had this in my favs for later reference even though I personally haven't tried it):

I believe this is now easier to achieve using Rust Cross (https://github.com/rust-embedded/cross) from the Rust embedded team.

There is also an example: https://gitlab.com/Spindel/rust-cross-example/ based on the article: https://www.modio.se/cross-compiling-rust-binaries-to-armv7.html